# git bash: navigating to project folder

Tags: windows-7, git

I have installed **Git bash** and I haven't used it yet. I want to run few commands to install some modules, but I don't know how to navigate to my project folder.

My project folder: `C:\xampp\htdocs\server\Symfony`

My OS: `Windows 7`

I usually do this in command prompt by

```
cd xampp\htdocs\server\Symfony
```

I want to run these [commands](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/workflow/new_project_git.html)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In git bash, you'll need to use paths of the form:

```
/driveletter/rest/of/the/path
```

Try:

1. Using the full path to the project directory in your call to `cd` (e.g `cd /c/xampp/htdocs/server/Symfony`
2. Try issuing the proper relative path based on which directory you are currently in. You can determine your current directory by issuing the `pwd` command (print working directory).